# Esconder ScrollBar da div com overflow: auto

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tenho uma div `.content` que agrupa todo conteúdo do site com o seguinte css:

```
margin: 15px 12px;
background: #fff;
padding: 20px;
height: calc(100vh - 30px);
overflow: auto;
```

Meu body tem um `background: #222` diferente, pra simular uma borda.
Está 100% funcional, porém, quero remover aquela barra lateral do lado da div principal. Se eu colocar um `overflow: hidden;` no meu `.content`, o Scroll some, juntamente com a possibilidade de rolar a página. Alguma solução em jQuery ou mesmo em puro CSS (que funcione, também, fora do Chrome)?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ ai se dá um truque para ela sumir...

Comment: Não funciona no Firefox.

Comment: hum... e esse...v se ajuda:https://coderwall.com/p/4wa6ba/hide-browser-scroll-bars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No StackOverflow em Inglês responderam uma questão similar, que acredito que resolva o seu problema: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20447620/6762369

```
.div {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    height: 214px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 452px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#inner{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Nesta questão deixaram um exemplo no fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sp95S/1/